# Java synchronize 2 threads in parallel

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

-----------------SOLVED , Thank you for your suggestions ! ------------

I have the following code where I have an array of numbers. I want to create 2 threads who execute in parallel. First thread to print number value and second thread multiply.
Here is my code

```
class Synchronize {

    private boolean writeable = true;

    public synchronized void numbers() {
        {
            while (!writeable) {
                try {
                    wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }
            writeable = false;
            notify();
        }
    }

    public synchronized void multiply() {
        while (writeable) {
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
        writeable = true;
        notify();
    }
}

class Numbers
        extends Thread {

    private Synchronize s;
    int   numbers = 0;
    int[] array;

    Numbers(String name, Synchronize s, int[] array) {
        super(name);
        this.s = s;
        this.array = array;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i <= array.length - 1; i++) {
                System.out.print("\nIn " + getName() + " number is " + array[i] + "\t");
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                s.numbers();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}


class Multiply
        extends Thread {

    private Synchronize s;
    int   multiply = 1;
    int[] array;

    Multiply(String name, Synchronize s, int array[]) {
        super(name);
        this.s = s;
        this.array = array;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i <= array.length - 1; i++) {
                multiply = multiply * array[i];
                System.out.print("\nIn " + getName() + " multiply is " + multiply + "\t");
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                s.multiply();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}


public class NewThread {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int array[] = {
                1,
                4,
                5,
                2,
                7,
                8,
                9
        };

        Synchronize s = new Synchronize();
        new Numbers("Thread #1 ", s, array).start();
        new Multiply("Thread #2 ", s, array).start();
    }
}
```

Code output is like:

```
In Thread #1  number is 1   
In Thread #2  multiply is 1     
In Thread #1  number is 4   
In Thread #2  multiply is 4     
In Thread #2  multiply is 20    
In Thread #1  number is 5   
In Thread #1  number is 2   
In Thread #2  multiply is 40    
In Thread #1  number is 7
In Thread #1  number is 8   
In Thread #2  multiply is 280   
In Thread #2  multiply is 2240  
In Thread #1  number is 9   
In Thread #2  multiply is 20160
```

How I want it to be

```
In Thread #1  number is 1   
In Thread #2  multiply is 1   
In Thread #1  number is 4   
In Thread #2  multiply is 4     
In Thread #1  number is 5
In Thread #2  multiply is 20    
In Thread #1  number is 2   
In Thread #2  multiply is 40    
In Thread #1  number is 7   
In Thread #2  multiply is 280   
In Thread #1  number is 8   
In Thread #2  multiply is 2240  
In Thread #1  number is 9   
In Thread #2  multiply is 20160
```

I don't want method with queue... I would like just to modify this code if anyone know how to do.

Comment: I just run your code in my machine.. the output is exactly What You want to be..

Comment: I know, right, but only sometimes.... Can you run it again please? like 5 times?

Comment: If I run it first time it works (sometime) ...then if I try to run it few more times, it will print like first output and I can't explain myself why

Comment: @ClaudiuM it is just a guess, but I believe the printing is not synchronized, try to add `System.out.flush()` to your threads (after `println`)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `System.out.println()` is outside of synchronization block and therefore although evaluation is correctly serialized, printing the results may swap the order.

What you can do is to wrap `System.out.println()` into `Runnable`, pass it to `numbers(Runnable printer)` and `multiply(Runnable printer)` and call the `printer.run()` from within the synchronized methods.

Comment: You can test this by commenting the values printing sout and print different  sample strings from `numbers()` and `multiply()`.

Comment: @Zbynek Vyskovsky - kvr000 I need to think about that Runnable printer as parameter, but I'm sure it will work. I'll let you know when I'm done. Thank you !

Comment: @Zbynek Vyskovsky - kvr000 I made it, in `Synchronize` class, I gave to `numbers(Object t)` and `multiply(Object t)` parameters of type `Object`, and I wrote there in each one `System.out.print(t);` In my numbers class I wrote `s.numbers("\nIn "+getName()+" number is " + array[i] + "\t");` and in multiply class `s.multiply("\nIn "+getName()+" multiply is " + multiply + "\t");` and now it works. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution is to use `flush` as I mentioned in comment.

```
            System.out.print("\nIn " + getName() + " number is " + array[i] + "\t");
            System.out.flush();
```

Note: it is interesting, that in Eclipse IDE it was synchronized when printed to console and on command line it was not (if someone wants to test it).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion !  But it don't work :(, I am using Eclipse IDE too

Answer (score 0):

I see no need of using your `Synchronize` class

you are synchronizing methods `numbers()` and `multiply()` where as these two methods will not be called by two threads as per your lock `main` method until unless this program started externally more than once. So no point of making them as synchronized.

For the printing alternatively is only happening by this statement `Thread.sleep(1000)` in each thread class (Not all the times but some times), it wont print all the times alternatively as its depends upon the second thread to complete its task within mentioned time in `Thread.sleep()` of other thread.

if you want to try, you can comment these lines in both the classes

```
   s.numbers()
   s.multiply()
```

still you can see the expected output at least once,

Comment: Yes, I did this before :) and I seen that my program works without them. But I think I need some synchronization in order to make them print like my last output sequence, and yes, I can see expected at least once, but I want always :)

Comment: Before , I did alternate way, I mean, Thread 1 and then Thread 2 appear, and then again thread 1, and again thread 2, and it works !